# How to have different details per contract?

Tags: docusignapi

Is this possible using the DocuSign API?

I do not have back-end development, so I am trying to come up with a solution which does not need a back-end or a database.

- Bulk send out all envelopes using the UI
- Get list of recipients via API
- Have a email log in on my bespoke website which compares the user login input with the list of recipients to see if there is a match
- If there is a match direct the user to the DocuSign view so they can sign their specific contract

The problem I am experiencing is that each user has a different renewal price in the contract. It seems you have to create the envelope via the API when the user comes onto my website. How do I know which renewal price to include when creating the envelope without my own back-end server?

Answer (score 0):

There's no technical issue here. The issue you present is a use-case, or user flow challenge.
It's unclear where the renewal price is coming from. So I'm going to assume it comes from an employee that enters it. They can enter it in the envelope itself as a **text tab**. They "sign" the envelope just so that they can update this value. Then the real signer, the customer sees it with the correct value.

So, for a single customer you need an envelope **with 2 recipients**, the first enters the renewal price, the second signs the contract.

For **bulk send** you create a **template** like this, where the first signer is fixed and send it to many customers. The employee (or employees, it can be a **signing group** if it's more than one person) would have to first fill the renewal price before the envelope is sent to the customer for signature.
(which means you'll have to use different values for the **routing_order**, 1, and 2 so that they don't get it until the price is entered).